# Output Elements In a Specified Range

Tags: python

I need to write a program that first gets a list of integers from input. That list is followed by two more integers representing lower and upper bounds of a range. Then output all integers from the list that are within that range (inclusive of the bounds).

For example, if the input is:

```
27 200 49 71
0 60
```

the output should be:

```
27 49
```

**This is what I have so far:**

```
input_numbers = input().split(' ')
input_range = input().split(' ')

for number in input_numbers:
    if input_range[0] <= number <= input_range[1]:
        print('{}'.format(number), end = ' ')
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string, you have to cast the numbers to integers, i.e.:

```
input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
input_range = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]

for number in input_numbers:
    if input_range[0] <= number <= input_range[1]:
        print('{}'.format(number), end = ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` method gives a `string`, then you `split()` so you have an array of `string`, so you comparison `<` is done on string and not on `int`,  so the order you use is the lexicographical (alphabetical) order, where `'0' < '200' < '60'`

---

You can convert to `int` each one at the comparison moment

```
for number in input_numbers:
    if int(input_range[0]) <= int(number) <= int(input_range[1]):
        print('{}'.format(number), end=' ')
```

But the best is to convert the values, once, after getting them from user (alo provide a text to `input`, that helps to know what to write, and not wait without knowing the code expects something)

```
input_numbers = list(map(int, input("Please input values: ").split()))
input_range = list(map(int, input("Please 2 boundaries").split()))

for number in input_numbers:
    if input_range[0] <= number <= input_range[1]:
        print('{}'.format(number), end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it:

```
numbers = map(int, input().split())
ran = range(*map(int, input().split()))

out = [n for n in numbers if n in ran]
print(*out)
#27 49
```

Note: The method `str.split` splits by white spaces by default.